# how to filter data and hide that specific data from the rest

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve tried to search and filter a specific data and hide it from the rest while showing the rest of the data in a userform

I’ve tried to “reverse code” the one i have for filtering certain data and only showing it on the userform but lack proper knowledge on excel to do it

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click() 'Filter Button
   If Me.txtSearch.value = "" Then
      MsgBox "Please Enter the search value.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Search"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   
   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
   
   Dim iColumn As Integer
   Dim ish As Long
   Dim isht As Long
   
   ish = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Application.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   
   If Me.cmbAdvanced.value = Empty Then
      MsgBox "Please Select Search Criteria"
      
      Exit Sub
   End If
   
   iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.cmbAdvanced.value, sh.Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
   
   If sh.FilterMode = True Then
      sh.AutoFilterMode = False
   End If
   
   sht.Cells.Clear
   sh.AutoFilter.Range.Copy sht.Range("A1")
   
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   isht = sht.Range("A" & Application.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   
   Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12
   
   If isht > 1 Then
      Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet2!A1:O" & isht
      MsgBox "Records Found"
   Else
      MsgBox "No Record Found"
   End If
   
   sh.AutoFilterMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far and state your problem. Otherwise, your question would be closed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry added it now!!

Comment: What happens when your code runs?  What does it do (or not do) and how is that different from what you want to happen?